# Share Google+ button issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to add share button to my website and I have chosed to use 'sharrre.com' script all work's fine For twitter and Facebook but for google+ button it's not shown 
This is my code :

```
$('#twitter').sharrre({
  share: {
    twitter: true
  },
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  buttons: { twitter: {via: '_JulienH'}},
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('twitter');
  }
});

$('#facebook').sharrre({
  share: {
    facebook: true
  },
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('facebook');
  }
});
$('#googleplus').sharrre({
  share: {
    googlePlus: true
  },
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('googlePlus');
  }
});
```

Full code see my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ZpF/) 
And I followed [this demo](http://sharrre.com/example1.html)

So can any one tell me why Google+ button don't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured The problem For my googleplus script i forgot to add `urlCurl` option. 
This is Google+ Old function :

```
 $('#googleplus').sharrre({
  share: {
    googlePlus: true
  },
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('googlePlus');
  }
});
```

And this is the new one :

```
    $('#googleplus').sharrre({
  share: {
    googlePlus: true
  },
  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  urlCurl: '',
  click: function(api, options){
    api.simulateClick();
    api.openPopup('googlePlus');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a correct *cURL url parameter*.

```
$('#google').sharrre({
  share: {
        googlePlus: true
  },
  urlCurl: '/ts-includes/sharrre.php',
  template: '<a class="box" href="#"><div class="count" href="#">{total}</div><div class="share"><span></span>+1</div></a>',

  enableHover: false,
  enableTracking: true,
  click: function(api, options){
        api.simulateClick();
        api.openPopup('googlePlus');
  }
});
```

For WordPress I'm using: `urlCurl: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/theme-includes/sharrre.php'`

Remember to have the `sharrre.php` in the right location on your server/localhost.

Issue here -> https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a file. The code is looking for sharrre.php (which is included in the download for sharrre)

In the test I ran it looked for it in the same directory where you have the file that uses it (or you could just include it). Giving access to that file will fix your problem.

Comment: Can you explain litle bit more, or just modifie The Jsfiddle in way that it works?

Comment: I can't modify the fiddle to make it work because it requires PHP. Essentially instead of an html file you need a php file that has code to include the sharrre.php file. Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: So I have to try it in local machine ? if it's true should I add some Line code to my existing Code (code of JSfiddle) ??

Comment: Let's say you have your web root. In that you have the HTML file, a CSS file and a JS file. You also need one more file... sharrre.php. It is included in the sharrre download. If it is in the same location as the rest of the files Google plus will work.

Answer (score 0):

The easily missed but very important key to remember is having the sharrre.php file placed in the same location as the sharrre.js file as Stuart touched on above. Hope I don't get dinged for dupe...this is helped me.

I tried everything to no avail until I placed the sharrre.php in the same folder with .js file.